# Gmail search query not returning all "Today's" mails for Primary label

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Say today is 12/12/2014 and I want to search all mails for Today only in my Primary label in Inbox. I type this query in Gmail search bar:

```
in: inbox -category:{social promotions updates forums}  after: 2014/12/11
```

With this I get all today's emails in my Primary label of Gmail inbox, except for few auto-generated emails, e.g. Amazon.com sending some autogenerated emails etc. Please tell me what modification I should do in my query above to get all missing email threads too in search result.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that Gmail provides these 4 labels as part of Inbox: social, promotions, updates, forums.

So if a user has not selected to specifically see any of these 4 labels as tabbed category, then all those emails which should lie in that category will show up in Primary label of Inbox. In the below screenshot, as you can see, I have not selected "Updates" category in Gmail.

[image]

Example: If a user has chosen not to see "Updates" category, then all emails which should have shown up in that category will show up in Primary category. For this reason, if I query below in Gmail search bar expecting to see everything that is there in my primary category, I won't see all of those emails:

```
in: inbox -category:{social promotions updates forums}  after: 2014/12/11
```

Answer (score 1):

Settings >  Inbox > Inbox Section.

add a section with the following rule:

```
newer_than:1d
```

every time you go to your inbox or refresh the page the inbox section will apply the rule and you will get messages of today.

---

> "Inbox sections" will show up if you change the Inbox Type from "Default" to any other setting. Then the "Categories" will disappear and replaced with "Inbox sections" (followed by "Inbox unread count").  -- added by [user3250493](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/122933/user3250493)

Comment: I cannot see an "Inbox Section" under "Settings > Inbox"? Nor a way to "add a section" here? Can you provide a screenshot?